# Estimate a upper bound of an infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Assume $a>0$ and $a_n \geq 0$. how to verify that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{(a+S_n)^{3/2}}\leq \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+x)^{3/2}}\mathrm{d}x$$
where $S_n = a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$

Thanks very much

Comment: People would be more willing to help ... if you show some of your work ... or anything that you have attempted

Comment: @DannyCheuk. Thanks for your advise. I will add some my attemptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_{n}}\frac{dx}{ (a+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \geq \int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_n} \frac{dx}{(a+S_{n})^\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{S_n - S_{n-1}}{(a+S_n)^\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{a_n}{(a+S_n)^\frac{3}{2}}$$